# Proguard referenced field not found

Tags: gradle, android-studio, proguard

I'm trying to use proguard with my gradle project, however, there is a problem with one of my library classes:

The error:

`Warning:com.example.MediaView: can't find referenced field 'android.content.Context mContext' in program class com.example.MediaView`

In my proguard.txt there are entries required for android apps:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keep class com.example.MediaView
```

Also the `com.example.MediaView` comes from a library, and it extends `android.widget.FrameLayout`

Any idea how to get rid of this warning? (beside the -dontwarn toggle)

Thanks in advance!